# Is there a setting to force ignore invalid geometries when performing spatial analysis in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, spatial-analyst, geometry

When performing spatial joins I get no results due to geometry errors in one of the layers, but there is a note saying to force ignore geometry errors in the log. Where can I activate this setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In QGIS 3, go to Settings tab, Options, navigate to Processing and expand the General settings. For "Invalid features filtering" select "Do not filter (better performance)" from the corresponding dropdown menu.

Comment: No problem @Rob Bob, glad to help!